# ZXing initialize problemn on iOS and WindowsPhone

Tags: c#, ios, mobile, windows-phone, zxing

I developed a mobile application to scan QRCode in C # using Xamarin Forms.

I have issues starting MobileBarCodeScanning iOS and WindowsPhone.

I am using [this guide](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) as an example

The main code is in PCL, as I understand, must initialize the MobileBarCodeScanning on each platform. Android worked perfectly. I added the following line of code in MainActivity.cs:

```
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
```

The guide also has a WindowsPhone and iOS example, which are located inside AppDelegate.cs and MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.WindowsPhone.ZXingScannerViewRenderer.Init();
```

But it does not work in iOS and shows no error, the application closes when I try to start the camera. WindowsPhone does not find it in ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms, it gives the following error:

> The type or namespace WindowsPhone does not exist in the namespace 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms' (are you missing and assembly reference?)

On Android I had to add the permission to use the camera in Manifest.xml, I did not found anything like this for the other platforms.

I also found another way to boot via Android with the following line of code:

```
ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);
```

It worked perfectly, but the other platforms gave error again. I've already try to uninstall and install all packages again.

Could help me with this case?

Comment: seems like they don't support windows phone 8.1 : [link](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/291).
they only support windows phone 8 and windows UWP